# Angular - Handle HTTP response with DTO

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient, rxjs-observables

I can't seem to find a complete example of how to handle a complex Angular HTTP response.
I am using Angular 16.

The backend API I am trying to communicate with supplies a DTO (Data Transfer Object) like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "joe",
    "age": 40
  },
  "success": true,
  "message": "completed successfully"
}
```

In Angular, I am expecting to:

1. Use HttpClient to get the data
2. Have an if statement to check the HTTP status
3. If 200 OK - Do some kind of mapping of the JSON data to a model
4. Else return an error message for the front end
5. Return an observable

My own attempts have failed, but here is what I currently have:

Models/http_response.ts:

```
export interface HttpResponse {
    status: string;
    data: any;
    success: string;
    message: string;
}
```

Models/user.ts:

```
export interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Services/api.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpResponse } from '../models/http_response';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {
    constructor( private http: HttpClient ){ }

    getData(): Observable<HttpResponse> {

        // This definently is not correct
        return this.http.get(`${your_api_url}/Data`, {observe:'response'}).pipe(map((res: any) => {
            if(res){
                console.log(`inflow_data.service - 200 OK`);
                result = { status: res.status, data: res.Data.json(), success: res.Success, message: res.Message}
            }
            else {
                console.log(`inflow_data.service - Error! HttpStatus: ${res.status}`);
                result = { status: res.status, data: undefined, success: res.Success, message: res.Message}
            }
        }).subscribe(result => { return result });
    }

}
```

pages/page1/page1.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service'
import { HttpResponse } from '../models/http_response';
import { User } from '../models/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page1',
  templateUrl: './page1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page1.component.scss']
})


export class Page1 implements OnInit {

  // I should be able to grab the data from the Observable and feed it into a table or whatever
  dataSource: User[] = [];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

    async ngOnInit() {
      this.onGetData();
    }

    onGetData():void {
        this.apiService.getData().subscribe((response: HttpResponse) => {
          console.log(`Http response was - Status: ${response.status} Success: ${response.success} Data: ${response.data}`);

          if(response.success){
           this.dataSource = response.data;
          }
        });
    }

}
```

You can kind of see what I am trying to do. There are probably several things wrong with the above code. As I said, I couldn't find a complete example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code:

1. In the `getData` method, you shouldn't subscribe to the Observable while your method is expected to return `Observable<HttpResponse>`.
2. You incorrectly get the response body. Since you are applying `{observe:'response'}`, to get the response body you should use `res.body`. Another concern is to make sure that the field name you tried to get from the response body must be exactly the same, which is lowercase according to the attached JSON snippet.

**Updated:** With `observe: "response` which will result in an `Observable<HttpResponse>` (`HttpResponse` from [`@angular/common/http`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse)), you can use [`ok`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponseBase#ok) property to check whether the response is successful (status code with 2XX).

3. Your `data` field from the JSON is an object, you can't assign it to `dataSource` which is an array. Instead, you should add the object into array with `Array.push()`.

> api.service.ts

```
getData(): Observable<HttpResponse> {
  return this.http.get(`${your_api_url}/Data`, {observe:'response'}).pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      let responseBody = res?.body;
      let result: HttpResponse;
      if (res.ok) {
        console.log(`inflow_data.service - 200 OK`);
        result = {
          status: res.status,
          data: responseBody.data,
          success: responseBody.success,
          message: responseBody.message,
        };
      } else {
        console.log(`inflow_data.service - Error! HttpStatus: ${res.status}`);
        result = {
          status: res.status,
          data: undefined,
          success: responseBody?.success,
          message: responseBody?.message,
        };
      }

      return result;
    })
  );
}
```

> page1.component

```
this.apiService.getData().subscribe((response: HttpResponse) => {
  console.log(
    `Http response was - Status: ${response.status} Success: ${response.success} Data: ${response.data}`
  );

  if (response.success) {
    this.dataSource.push(response.data);
  }
});
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uf6uve?file=src%2FServices%2Fapi.service.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much Yong! Yes, I got it working. I hope this helps other people too.